# Any ideas on how to remove a knockout template from M2 (at the checkout)?

Tags: knockoutjs, magento-2.2.5

The template in question is

> vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/frontend/web/template/payment/discount.html

and it shows at the checkout

The rule that places the template in

> vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

is

```
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount</item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by disabling the component in an overriding XML file.

app/design/frontend/Vendorname/ThemeName/Magento_SalesRule/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount</item>
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: LOL, piece of cake.